# How to update (refresh) console screen?

Tags: c, windows, console

I'm writing a program that shows some information on screen and I want them to be updated each second.

What should I do?

I'm writing a C console application on Windows.

Comment: I am not sure about a clear console method, but you could try to detect the height of your console and add the appropriate amount of linebreaks.

Answer (score 2):

The Pianist, you can work with a console using WinAPI functions.

```
HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
if (!hConsole)
    return;
```

After that determine the cursor position:

```
CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi = {0};
GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsole, &csbi);
COORD coordCur = csbi.dwCursorPosition;
```

And...

```
while (TRUE) {  // your cycle goes here
    // ...
    // now you can change position of the cursor
    coordCur.X = newX;
    coordCur.Y = newY;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, coordCur);
    // and print any information from the new position
    printf("..."); // old text will be replaced
}
```

So you don't need to clear and refresh all console if you want to change a small piece of text.

ps. Don't forget to release a handle:

```
CloseHandle(hConsole);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on Windows, you can do this:

```
system('cls')
```

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Press enter to clear the screen.");
    getchar();
    system("cls");
    return 0;
}
```

If you are developing using Microsoft Visual Studoo and you want to programmatically clear the screen by outputting spaces, see Example 2 at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682022(v=vs.85).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

If you had searched google before asking, you would have found [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10515/) right in the first results.

To quote one of the methods:

> **Windows:**
>
> ```
> #include <windows.h>
>
> void ClearScreen()
>   {
>   HANDLE                     hStdOut;
>   CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
>   DWORD                      count;
>   DWORD                      cellCount;
>   COORD                      homeCoords = { 0, 0 };
>
>   hStdOut = GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );
>   if (hStdOut == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return;
>
>   /* Get the number of cells in the current buffer */
>   if (!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo( hStdOut, &csbi )) return;
>   cellCount = csbi.dwSize.X *csbi.dwSize.Y;
>
>   /* Fill the entire buffer with spaces */
>   if (!FillConsoleOutputCharacter(
>     hStdOut,
>     (TCHAR) ' ',
>     cellCount,
>     homeCoords,
>     &count
>     )) return;
>
>   /* Fill the entire buffer with the current colors and attributes */
>   if (!FillConsoleOutputAttribute(
>     hStdOut,
>     csbi.wAttributes,
>     cellCount,
>     homeCoords,
>     &count
>     )) return;
>
>   /* Move the cursor home */
>   SetConsoleCursorPosition( hStdOut, homeCoords );
>   }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

There's a [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/99261) on that topic.

> Two options:
>
> 1. Write a function that will programmatically clear the screen
>
>    ```
>    /* Standard error macro for reporting API errors */ 
>    #define PERR(bSuccess, api){if(!(bSuccess)) printf("%s:Error %d from %s \ 
>        on line %d\n", __FILE__, GetLastError(), api, __LINE__);}
>
>    void cls( HANDLE hConsole )
>    {
>        COORD coordScreen = { 0, 0 };    /* here's where we'll home the
>                                            cursor */ 
>        BOOL bSuccess;
>        DWORD cCharsWritten;
>        CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi; /* to get buffer info */ 
>        DWORD dwConSize;                 /* number of character cells in
>                                            the current buffer */ 
>
>        /* get the number of character cells in the current buffer */ 
>
>        bSuccess = GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo( hConsole, &csbi );
>        PERR( bSuccess, "GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo" );
>        dwConSize = csbi.dwSize.X * csbi.dwSize.Y;
>
>        /* fill the entire screen with blanks */ 
>
>        bSuccess = FillConsoleOutputCharacter( hConsole, (TCHAR) ' ',
>           dwConSize, coordScreen, &cCharsWritten );
>        PERR( bSuccess, "FillConsoleOutputCharacter" );
>
>        /* get the current text attribute */ 
>
>        bSuccess = GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo( hConsole, &csbi );
>        PERR( bSuccess, "ConsoleScreenBufferInfo" );
>
>        /* now set the buffer's attributes accordingly */ 
>
>        bSuccess = FillConsoleOutputAttribute( hConsole, csbi.wAttributes,
>           dwConSize, coordScreen, &cCharsWritten );
>        PERR( bSuccess, "FillConsoleOutputAttribute" );
>
>        /* put the cursor at (0, 0) */ 
>
>        bSuccess = SetConsoleCursorPosition( hConsole, coordScreen );
>        PERR( bSuccess, "SetConsoleCursorPosition" );
>        return;
>    }
>    ```
> 2. Use a system function (not very pretty; requires starting a shell and a command)
>
>    ```
>    system("cls");
>    ```